# Export Env variable from Java

Tags: java, python, unix

I've following export in my .bash_profile

```
export PATH=/export/to/path/tools:$PATH
export PATH=/export/to/path/:$PATH
```

and when i run my code through command line and through python, every thing works fine but same path is not recognized when i run my java code. (python and java are running code to achieve exact same functionality)

Can you tell what additional step is required in Java to export these paths?
I am on Mac env.

Comment: How are your running java code and how in Java are you using the path

Comment: Please [post some code](http://sscce.org/) to show what is wrong and where.

Comment: When we have any export in .bash_profile, it is loaded by shell terminal, but java has a different runtime so don't we need these env exports in Java runtime? Here is sample code. export ANT_HOME=/user/android/sdk/Ant (It could be anything) in my .bash_profile. Now i launch a new terminal and run "ant clean" and this works fine. But when i use my java code and call "ant clean" it does not work.

Comment: In that case, in your Java, what does `System.out.println(System.getEnv("ANT_HOME"))` gives as an output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have:

File `/tmp/tp`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo toto > /tmp/toto
```

File `.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH=/tmp:$PATH
```

File `Test.java`:

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(System.getenv("PATH"));
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("tp").waitFor();
    }
}
```

When I run the following, I get:

```
matth@matth:~/code/tmp$ bash
matth@matth:~/code/tmp$ java Test
/tmp:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
acq@dgacq:~/code/tmp$ ll /tmp/toto 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 acq acq 5 juin  10 00:35 /tmp/toto     <<<------ Created just now
```